# Unable to save changes of Android platform in Facebook developer console

Tags: facebook, expo, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an Facebook developer account and added iOS platform and provided necessary details in that and then clicked on the button 'Save Changes' and changes are saved perfectly but when I added Android platform and gave hash key and then clicked on the 'Save Changes',changes are not saved and Android platform is not being added.

I am using expo facebook authentication for my app. I tried loggin in using iOS mobile, it's working perfectly but when I tried logging in using Android mobile, it's not working. Pop is not shown and error message 'Facebook Login Error: Error: An error occurred while trying to log in to Facebook' is being printed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue after a day by logging from another browser(Edge) other than Chrome.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me right now . Any follow up on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried logging in using another browser or incognito mode?

Answer (score 2):

Same here... Then I managed to save my changes by visiting the "Quick Start" section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That happened with me because the package name I used does not exist in the Play Store. In my case that was what I wanted because this app was to be used for development and I install it using the APK directly.

Unfortunatelly, I received no errors, it just wasn't saving and I didn't know why. When I pressed enter in the field using a non existent package, the text field remained with the package name like a normal text, while with an existing package it changed the name including a border and an `x` button to remove it.

With an existing name I was able to save, and when editing putting the fake package name, it showed that the name may not be valid, but allowed saving (as opposed when adding the platform, that gave no feedback whatsoever and didn't allow saving the platform).